# Drop Pin on current location

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview

I am building an iOS app and need to be able to place a pin where the user currently is! For some reason I have been having an awful time getting it to work! I tried the following code but was faced with an error.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
        annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
        return annView;
        [annView release];



    }
}
```

The error was:
Control May Reach End of non-void function.

Thank you so much for the help! '
Appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works fine in the Xcode iPhone simulator:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import MapKit;

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mapView setDelegate:self];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

    // zoom to region containing the user location
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    // add the annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"The Location";
    point.subtitle = @"Sub-title";
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}

@end
```

Comment: So would i just call this in my viewController? That is what I did and nothing happened :)

Comment: @NicholasGibson Yes, this would go into the `UIViewController` that is your `MKMapViewDelegate`. The `self.mapView` is an `IBOutlet` to the map view in your Storyboard.

Comment: Okay thanks! The only problem is that nothing happens with this code? Like my current location is shown because i am running     mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
in my viewDidLoad but your code does not place a pin on my current location. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @NicholasGibson Are you testing in the iPhone simulator or on an actual device? If you're using the simulator, then make sure the scheme location is set to a certain location (I believe it defaults to none).

Comment: My iPhone. Should this code place a pin automatically or should I tap and hold on my current location?

Comment: @NicholasGibson I revised my answer for you. It works fine in the iPhone simulator and should also work on a device.

Answer (score 0):

When a method has a return type then something must be returned in all conditions, you are only returning something in the if branch, not otherwise. The compiler requires you to also return something when the if statement evaluates to false - that is the reason why you are getting the compilation error.

Incidentally the line

```
 [annView release];
```

can never get executed because you are returning before then. But is there any reason why you are calling this? i.e. attempting to use non ARC code? Have you copied this line from somewhere (which is old code)

Comment: Yeah I go this from an old StackOverflow question and it did not work for me!

Comment: The non return is the reason for the compilation error. You should be building using ARC which should flag the attempt to use release (though this is unrelated to your problem, its just a general comment)

Comment: Oh yeah I know! I just commented it out when I ran the code and still got the error. I did it like this //[annView release];